# Tokenize NSString twice in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, tokenize

I don't have much experience in objective-c, sorry if this is really obvious.

What I need is to split a NSString into tokens. The tokens are separated by spaces or by another sign (not a letter). The catch is that I want to keep the separators except when they are spaces.

Example phrase: "a b c,d's, e f." from this I would like to get:

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
","
"d"
"'"
"s"
","
"e"
"f"
"."
```

With this code:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *separators = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
[separators formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSArray *parse_array = [intext componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];
```

I get only the letters. If I just filter the whitespaces and NL I get the signs together with the letters. What i need is to perform two parsings in sequence (first the whitespaces and Nl and then the punctuation), but I really don't know how to do it in objective-c. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this to remove all the whitespace from a string:

```
NSArray * t = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
string = [t componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Then you could just iterate over the characters and turn them into `NSStrings`:

```
NSMutableArray *tokens = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [string length]; ++i) {
  unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:i];
  NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", character];
  [tokens addObject:token];
}
NSLog(@"%@", tokens);
```

Or if you didn't want to strip the whitespace before, you could do it in the loop:

```
NSMutableArray *tokens = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [string length]; ++i) {
  unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:i];
  if ([[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character]) {
    continue;
  }
  NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", character];
  [tokens addObject:token];
}
NSLog(@"%@", tokens);
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, but my example sentence had only letters, but the purpose would be to use this to parse words too. I'll add some buffer and adapt a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Check out my open source Cocoa String tokenizing/parsing toolkit: ParseKit:

http://parsekit.com

ParseKit contains an extremely powerful/flexible tokenizer class: `PKTokenizer`. By default, `PKTokenizer` will silently consume white space tokens without reporting them. (In this case that is what you want, but that behavior can be configured if you don't.)

Here's how you could use `PKTokenizer` for this particular task:

```
// create the tokenizer with your string
NSString *inStr = @"a b c,d's, e f.";
PKTokenizer *t = [PKTokenizer tokenizerWithString:inStr];

// configure the tokenizer to not allow apostrophes inside words (that's the default)
[t.wordState setWordChars:NO from:'\'' to:'\''];

// loop thru the input and concat the non-whitespace chars
PKToken *eof = [PKToken EOFToken];
PKToken *tok = nil;

NSMutableArray *outStrs = [NSMutableArray array];
while ((tok = [t nextToken]) != eof) {
    [outStrs addObject:tok.stringValue];
}
```

`outStrs` contains:

"a"
    "b"
    "c"
    ","
    "d"
    "'"
    "s"
    ","
    "e"
    "f"
    "."

ParseKit might be a little bit of overkill for this particular task. But if you have several similar tasks, it is probably worth checking out, as it may save you time/pain.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code. This works for letters or words:

```
//parse the phrase into tokens. Punctuation will be tokenized too.
NSMutableArray *tokens = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger last_word_start = -1;
//
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [myPhrase length]; ++i) 
{
    unichar character = [myPhrase characterAtIndex:i];
    if ([[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character]) 
    {
        if (last_word_start >= 0) 
            [tokens addObject:[myPhrase substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(last_word_start, i-last_word_start)]];
        last_word_start = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character])
        {
            if (last_word_start >= 0) 
                [tokens addObject:[myPhrase substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(last_word_start, i-last_word_start)]];
            [tokens addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", character]];
            last_word_start = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (last_word_start == -1)
                last_word_start = i;
        }
    }
}
//save pending letters
if (last_word_start >= 0) 
    [tokens addObject:[myPhrase substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(last_word_start, [myPhrase length]-last_word_start)]];
NSLog(@"Tokens for phrase '%@':",myPhrase);
NSLog(@"%@", tokens);
```

Thank you!